# How to order by a specific way?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Mysql table:

```
id | category    | image<br>
--------------------------------
0  | landscape   | image name
1  | panarimic   | image name
2  | portrait    | image name
3  | landscape   | image name
4  | landscape   | image name
5  | portait     | image name
```

I want to write mysql select that should get the landscapes first and than list others. How can i do that? i can add category number and make "order by" but is there another way without it?

Comment: First id never be 0 second `ORDER BY category ASC`. it will sort according to category name alphabatically

Comment: @Anant Thats only in case this is all his categories ..

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use `CASE EXPRESSION` in your `ORDER BY CLAUSE` :

```
SELECT t.id,t.category,t.image
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t.category = 'landscapes' then 1 else 0 end DESC,
         t.category
```

Comment: No problem, I'll appreciate an approval then @yavona

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  tableName 
ORDER BY 
  CASE
    WHEN category LIKE 'landscape' 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END DESC ;
```